# How to make child object shooting effect?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't have a shooting animation for it so i want to make some kind of shooting "animation" on my own when the object will fire bullets. I thought about making the object shaking but maybe shaking is not good enough.

The first problem is that my object is a child of my player hand and when i attached this script to the child object he is shaking but in other position and he not in the original position he should be. the object is still child of the player hand but the position when shaking is not in the player hand but some where else near it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShakeObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Random.insideUnitCircle * 0.01f;
    }
}
```

This is the shooting script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShootBullets : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float bulletDistance;
    public bool automaticFire = false;
    public float fireRate;
    public Rigidbody bullet;

    private float gunheat;
    private bool shoot = false;
    private GameObject bulletsParent;
    private GameObject[] startpos;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bulletsParent = GameObject.Find("Bullets");
        startpos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Pod_Weapon");
    }

    void Fire()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < startpos.Length; i++)
        {
            Rigidbody bulletClone = (Rigidbody)Instantiate(bullet, startpos[i].transform.position, startpos[i].transform.rotation, bulletsParent.transform);

            bulletClone.velocity = transform.forward * bulletDistance;
            Destroy(bulletClone.gameObject, 0.5f);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (automaticFire == false)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Fire();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (shoot == true)
            {
                    Fire();

                    shoot = false;
            }
        }

        if (gunheat > 0) gunheat -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (gunheat <= 0)
        {
            shoot = true;
            gunheat = fireRate;
        }
    }
}
```

Making the object firing bullets that i can do but making some effect like simulate shooting "animation" that's not sure how to do and if shaking is looks like shooting.

i want that each time a bullet is firing to make also shooting animation effect.

Comment: I don't really understand what exactly `shooting "animation"` refers to ... what exactly are you trying to achieve? I understand that you do shoot bullets but what is that animation / effect you are trying to implement?

Comment: @derHugo i mean something like when you are shooting a gun or even a sci fi weapon there is some kind of movement of the weapon when firing.  something like this very short video clip i recorded of my another project, im using a specific animation for the shooting but the animation is not fitting for the other project but this is what i mean the shooting effect.  not just bullets coming out the droid but something that fire them. not sure if it's a must but i think see an object with idle animation start firing bullets is not so realistic. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ucD3QYpRYQQ